# How to combine `.findAllAsync().asObservable()` with `copyFromRealm`?

Tags: realm, rx-java

I am using realm-java with `copyFromRealm` to create detached copies of the data, as I don't need the complexities of having *attached* objects.

I am trying to combine with RxJava, so using `findAllAsync().asObservable()` which works ok to produce an Observable of type `RealmResults`. However, this is still dealing with *attached* objects.

How do I convert this:

```
public Observable<RealmResults<MyClass>> find(String id) {
    return realm.where(MyClass.class)
            .equalTo("id", id)
            .findAllAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
}
```

to also make use of Realm's `realm.copyFromRealm(attachedRealmObject);` method so that every result is automatically copied from Realm, without having to iterate through the `RealmResults` list and detaching manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copyFromRealm` also works on collections, so the below should work?

```
public Observable<RealmResults<MyClass>> find(String id) {
        return realm.where(MyClass.class)
                .equalTo("id", id)
                .findAllAsync()
                .asObservable()
                .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
                .map(results -> realm.copyFromRealm(results))
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this works great. My custom realm abstraction made me think it wouldn't work on collections. User-error. Thanks.